# Any way to zip the RestLet StringRepresentation response

Tags: java, restlet

I am using restlet and returning xml response as StringRepresentation. One of my service need to return a large amount of data that makes the response size close to 5 MB.

Is there any way to zip this response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping it in an `EncodeRepresentation`should work psudocode:

```
return new EncodeRepresentation(Encoding.ZIP, StringRepresentation);
```

Do double check that I have selected the correct encoding for you there are a few options.